# Database schema and data management tools

Tags: database, sql, postgresql

I've been using [*Visual Paradigm*](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/) on both mac and linux to simutaneously manage my database's schema and example/test data during development. I have found their interface to only get buggier over time and would like to explore better management/development solutions.

1) Are there good community-recommended alternatives that both visually map the database schema and hold corresponding example data?

2) Alternately, I like the simple layout of tools such as [*GenMyModel*](http://www.genmymodel.com) which give a simple visual representation of database schema, without holding any of the test data. Are there good tools to integrate with the datamodel to hold the example/test data? I'm trying to avoid hand-writing the .ddl scripts which would be quite extensive.

The database schema is not static and is developing along with my application so the corresponding test data needs to be somewhat flexible.